# content does not fit on to the UI label

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 -(void) genResultView :(UIScrollView *) scroller  mainView :(float) labelTextSize :(float) textViewTxtSize;
{
    float imageViewW;
    float imageViewH;
    float padding;
    float labelH;
    float labelW;
    float textViewH;
    float textViewW;
    float lineH = 2.0f;
    float lineW;
    float titleFontSize;

    NSString *font = @"Georgia";
    UIColor *fontColour = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //make instances of objects here
    leftCharacterImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    rightCharacterImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    leftNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    rightNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    leftGenderLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    rightGenderLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    leftPerType = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    rightPerType = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    vsLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    compareText = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    mainView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height)];
    //Set frame & font sizes here
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        padding = 25;
        imageViewH = 90;
        imageViewW = 90;
        textViewH = 250;
        textViewW = 280;
        labelH = 30;
        labelW = 100;
        lineW = 300;
        titleFontSize = 11;


    } else {
        padding = 50;
        imageViewH = 200;
        imageViewW = 200;
        textViewH = 500;
        textViewW = 1000;
        labelH = 30;
        labelW = 200;
        lineW = 700;
        titleFontSize = 20;
    }
    //Set control sizes & locations
    //set imageview frames
    leftCharacterImage.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.size.width/2-imageViewW/2-imageViewW, padding+lineH, imageViewW,imageViewH);
    rightCharacterImage.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.size.width/2-imageViewW/2+imageViewW, padding+lineH,imageViewW ,imageViewH);
    //set label frames & text sizes
    [vsLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
    [vsLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Georgia-bold" size:titleFontSize]];
    [vsLabel setTextColor:fontColour];
   // vsLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    leftNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.size.width/2-labelW/2-imageViewW, padding + lineH +imageViewH,labelW ,labelH);
    [leftNameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: font size:labelTextSize]];
    [leftNameLabel setTextColor:fontColour];
    rightNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.size.width/2-labelW+imageViewW, padding + lineH + imageViewH,labelW ,labelH);
    [rightNameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: font size:labelTextSize]];
    [rightNameLabel setTextColor:fontColour];
    leftGenderLabel.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.size.width/2-labelW/2-imageViewW, padding + lineH + imageViewH + labelH,labelW ,labelH);
    [leftGenderLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: font size:labelTextSize]];
    [leftGenderLabel setTextColor:fontColour];
    rightGenderLabel.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.size.width/2-labelW+imageViewW, padding + lineH + imageViewH + labelH ,labelW ,labelH);
    [rightGenderLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: font size:labelTextSize]];
    [rightGenderLabel setTextColor:fontColour];
    leftPerType.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.size.width/2-labelW/2-imageViewW, padding + lineH + imageViewH + labelH + labelH,labelW ,labelH);
    [leftPerType setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: font size:labelTextSize]];
    [leftPerType setTextColor:fontColour];
    rightPerType.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.size.width/2-labelW+imageViewW, padding + lineH + imageViewH + labelH * 2,labelW ,labelH);
    [rightPerType setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: font size:labelTextSize]];
    [rightPerType setTextColor:fontColour];

    line2 = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    line2.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.size.width/2-lineW/2, padding + lineH + imageViewH + labelH * 3 + 10, lineW,lineH);
    [line2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [mainView addSubview:line2];

    vsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.size.width/2-labelW/2-imageViewW, padding + lineH + imageViewH + labelH * 3 + 25,(imageViewW + labelW *2)+10,labelH);

    //set text view frame

    compareText.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.size.width/2-labelW/2-imageViewW, padding + imageViewH + labelH * 3 + vsLabel.frame.size.height + 50,textViewW ,textViewH);
    [compareText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: font size:textViewTxtSize]];
    //
    [compareText setTextColor:fontColour];
    [compareText setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    compareText.numberOfLines = 0;
    //add to mainview
    [mainView addSubview:leftCharacterImage];
    [mainView addSubview:rightCharacterImage];
    [mainView addSubview:vsLabel];
    [mainView addSubview:leftNameLabel];
    [mainView addSubview:rightNameLabel];
    [mainView addSubview:leftGenderLabel];
    [mainView addSubview:rightGenderLabel];
    [mainView addSubview:leftPerType];
    [mainView addSubview:rightPerType];
    [mainView addSubview:compareText];
    //call compareResult

    [self genCompareResult];


    [tfcompareDescription boldHeadings:compareDescription :[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-bold" size:20.0] :[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:10.0]:compareText :tfcompareDescription.listOfRanges];
    [compareText setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
    [vsLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tips for %@ and %@ to work together more effectively:",characterType1,characterType2]];
    [compareText sizeToFit];
    [vsLabel sizeToFit];

    mainView.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.origin.x,mainView.frame.origin.y,mainView.frame.size.width,padding*5 + lineH + labelH*3 + compareText.frame.size.height+imageViewH);

    [scroller addSubview:mainView];
}
```

I just want to show some data on UILabel  when the code run it shows like that.I just want show the data fit on to the Ui label regardless of the device. What I want to do is I just want to keep the font line steady and change the label size according to the no of line in the description

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJD93.png)

Comment: First of all.. why are you using Frames.. secondly, how did you measure the size of the label? Finally.. the frame of your label has a problem with its width and height. The size may be too large to fit `mainView`.. so I suspect the calculations are incorrect.

Comment: @Brandon I just put the whole code.Can you tell what did I miss

Answer (score 0):

about " mainView.frame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.origin.x,mainView.frame.origin.y,mainView.frame.size.width,padding*5 + lineH + labelH*3 + compareText.frame.size.height+imageViewH);"

do you init the mainView.frame first?

you can print the mainView.frame.origin and mainView.frame.size to make sure whether is inited